# Which dinosaurs on the Island were actually from the Jurassic period?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

The Tyrannosaurus Rex, Velociraptor and Triceratops were all from the [Cretaceous period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous), not from the Jurassic period.

I'm guessing the name *Jurassic* "sounded" better than *Cretaceous*, hence the preferred name.

In the Jurassic Park franchise, which dinosaurs on the island were actually from the Jurassic period?  Were there any?

Comment: Are you asking about the films, the books, or both?

Comment: @Hypnosifl To be honest, I didn't consider the books when I was thinking about this.

Comment: Which films are you asking about? or are you asking about the whole franchise?

Comment: @RedCaio The franchise, which is why I included the two tags available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cloned_animals_in_Jurassic_Park) is a wikipedia page about the dinosaurs (and other prehistoric creatures) shown in the Jurassic Park movies (it also lists the ones mentioned in the books, but I take it from the comments you were just interested in the movies). The ones that actually lived in the Jurassic are:

Stegosaurus--appeared in films 2, 3, and 4.

[image]

Brachiosaurus--appeared in 1 and 3.

[image]

Dilophosaurus--appeared in 1.

[image]

Compsognathus--appeared in 2 and 3.

[image]

Apatosaurus--appeared in 4.

[image]

Dimorphodon--a pterosaur rather than a dinosaur, but it appeared in 4.

[image]

Ceratosaurus--appeared in 3.

[image]

Mamenchisaurus--appeared in 2.

[image]

Also, Metriacanthosaurus and Proceratosaurus did not appear in any movies, but their names appeared next to vials in cold storage in 1, and the name Metriacanthosaurus also appeared in a brochure in 4. Likewise, in 1 the name Segisaurus appeared on a map of Isla Nublar, though they weren't seen in the movie.

Comment: Wikipedia link is broken

Answer (score 3):

According to this site's listing of dinos from the Jurassic period
http://www.prehistory.com/timeline/jurassic.htm

Brachiosaurus (Jurassic Park)

Stegosaurus (Jurassic Park III / Jurassic World)

Comment: There was also another type of sauropod different from Brachiosaurus (the front legs were shorter than the back, unlike Brachiosaurus) in *The Lost World*, [this page](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Mamenchisaurus) identifies it as Mamenchisaurus which was from the Jurassic. Also, *The Lost World* featured the small dinosaur [Compsognathus](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Compsognathus) which was from the Jurassic. And Stegosaurus was also featured in *The Lost World* (Jurassic Park II).

Comment: "Compys" were also in the original book - they may have been shortly seen or referenced at one point in the original film but certainly not to the degree they were in the book

Comment: Yes, and if the question covers the books as well as the films, then a lot of the sauropods mentioned as being in the [Sauropod paddock](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Sauropod_Paddock) would probably have been from the Jurassic if we looked them all up.

Comment: Thought of one more: the inaccurately-portrayed [Dilophosaurus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilophosaurus) was in reality from the early Jurassic.

Comment: "they may have been shortly seen or referenced at one point in the original film" -- The Compys weren't featured at all in the *original* film, but they did have a couple of prominent scenes in *The Lost World* (the second film). My comments above about Mamenchisaurus and Stegosaurus were also about the film titled *The Lost World*, not the book.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The Compys featured in Crichton's novel though, being the opening chapter to Jurassic Park.